# Facebook returns only 25 photos

Tags: php, facebook, get, photos

I have some problems with album with more than 25 photos...
my code is:

```
$albumPictures = $facebook->api('/' . $album .'/photos','GET');
```

but if I look into $albumPictures I find only 25 photos...
can anyone help me please?

Comment: Without knowing ***anything at all*** about the FB API, I'm going to guess it limits the number of pictures you can retrieve to 25 per request so you can't assassinate their servers by retrieving a million pictures in a single request. It may allow you to specify some sort of count option to raise this to 50 or 100. You'll probably be better served checking out the FB API documentation before posting a question on SO for this type of thing.

Comment: ok, I would like to know how to set this sort of count option! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you forgotten to paginate to the next page?

There's a `paging` entry in the Graph API response with `next` and `previous` urls to retrieve the rest of the photos (assuming there were more than 25 photos in the album - the default query is 25 photos)

You could also just ask for all photos in a single request by calling `/ALBUM_ID/photos?limit=200`